# Spatial join if percentage of area is within

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-join

I have been performing spatial joins but there is a problem.  The geometries of both layers are slightly misaligned.  I would like to join by location where `parcels` are within `historic_subdistricts` and to keep both matching and non matching records.  The query below works but the problem is that `ST_Within` only works if geometry of one layer is completely contained by the other.

```
CREATE TABLE test_join AS
SELECT t.*, m.*
FROM parcels AS t
LEFT JOIN historic_subdistricts= AS m
ON ST_Within(t.geom, m.geom)
```

How would one write a query to perform a spatial join if 90% of the area of a parcel in `parcels` is within a subdistrict in `historic_subdistricts` ?

Here is a visualization of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try below query by getting the **intersected area** of both geometries and the **total area** of Parcel geometry, then get the **percentage** and compare it 90%:

```
CREATE TABLE test_join AS
SELECT t.*, m.*
FROM parcels AS t , historic_subdistricts AS m
where st_intersects(t.geom, m.geom) and    
(st_area(st_intersection(t.geom, m.geom))/st_area(t.geom)) > 0.9
```

Make sure both fields are indexed.

Comment: Thank you, this was an absolute life saver!

Answer (score 2):

My favourite trick for cases like this is to join on the centroids:

```
 SELECT parcel.id, historic_subdistricts.id
 FROM parcel JOIN historic_subdistricts
 ON ST_Contains(historic_subdistricts.geom, ST_Centroid(parcel.geom))
```

This neatly avoids double-counting, and unless your overlaps are really really large should correctly assign all your boundary shapes.

Comment: This is normally a good trick, but be careful depending on your polygon shapes. For some polygons, the centroid may be outside of the polygon. See the example here: http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Centroid.html If you have multipolygons, you need to take even more care.